# Ionic Framework can't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I want to build a hybrid mobile app with Ionic. Here is my first trial via [plunker](http://plnkr.co/BNNJWFvw6wFgBJ9zQM8g). As you can see, my plunker shows a blank page. I did inspect what's the problem, but still not found. My goal is to create a login page in first time my app starts, then users will be redirected into `home-page.html`. Since it's just example, I don't want any authentication code, I only need to have all those route/links work well.

Please take a look in my `index.html`, if I replace all those code within  ......  with a normal HTML tags, it's displaying as normal.

1. Head section:

   ```
   <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.1/js/ionic.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>

   <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   <script src="app.js"></script>
   ```
2. Body section

   ```
    <script id="templates/login.htm" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <ion-content>
          <h1>Login page</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="logIn()">Login Press</button>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home-page.htm" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view>
        <ion-content>
          <h1>Home Page</h1>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
   ```

In my `app.js`, I defined two states like this:

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })

    .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: 'templates/home-page.html'
    });
});

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $location) {
  $scope.logIn = function() {
  //$state.go('/home');
   alert('Clicked');
  };
});
```

Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why but it seams that your ng-templates are not found, you are getting 404 on 'templates/login.html'. When you are using `$stateProvider` you need to put `ui-view` to show/display your content. I have modify your plunker a little bit, move templates to a separate files and add ui-view, all it's working fine now, please check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bdQIWAQVQBTf7BLtER9i?p=preview).

Comment: Great. I also checked the `alert` message and the `$state.go`, they worked well. FYI, I copy those codes into my intel xdk project, with a little configuration, the `ng-click` doesn't work. But when I replace `ng-click` with `ui-sref`, it works. I think it's very strange if I use `ui-sref` to redirect user from login page to homepage.

Overall, many thanks for your help.

Comment: no probs, you can make it as a correct answer to close the thread, thanks !